# Stacked bar chart with tags as Y-axis in Azure Devops not possible?

Tags: azure-devops, charts, tags, yaxis, stacked-bar-chart

I try to make a stacked bar chart with Tags as Y-Asis, but does not seem possible, If I flip it and use tags as group by and state as y-axis it works.
Weird, any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places related to the stacked bar chart.

place 1: Flat list of work items query
But you can't group charts by 'Tags' field
Please see the doc for more details: [Create a flat-list query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=azure-devops#create-a-flat-list-query)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2lAS.png)

place 2:'Chart for Work Items' widget in 'Dashboard'
Here you could choose 'tags' both in Y-axis and Group by.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEtqG.png)

Hope it could do some help.

Comment: Does this explain your queries? If not, please kindly clarify what you mean and we will try to do further investigation.